# Application Insight continuous export not exporting the performance metrics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have setup an Azure AI account and deployed my application to a web role. I am able to see the performance related data on the portal but the continuous export is exporting all the data except the performance metrics. I have setup continuous export to export all the metrics.

Comment: what sku do you have of AI?

Comment: We have a premium account.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a calculated information, it won't be included in the exported data. Continuous export only sends the raw telemetry and let the user do whatever they want to do with that. Most of the performance related data might fall into that category. This might be the reason.

Here is what mentioned on this doc: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-telemetry/

> Other calculated metrics are not included. For example, we don't
>   export average CPU utilisation, but we do export the raw telemetry
>   from which the average is computed.

Comment: It makes sense certainly, though I wonder what raw data can be used to calculate 'Process CPU' counter... As far as I understand, I cannot just multiply 'Processor Time %' by the number of cores, because 'Processor Time %' is expected to show the total utilization of the CPU by all processes, while 'Process CPU' should show the share of my server process only.